# Flask - GET request to 'static' directory returns Error 404

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

Flask Documentation states:

> Dynamic web applications also need static files. That’s usually where
>   the CSS and JavaScript files are coming from. Ideally your web server
>   is configured to serve them for you, but during development Flask can
>   do that as well. Just create a folder called static in your package or
>   next to your module and it will be available at /static on the
>   application.

But in my webapp, when I try to acces `localhost:5000/static/`, I get a `404` error on the browser. What is more weird is that when I run it in debug mode, I get a `200` (ok) on the terminal, and `404` on the browser.

Could you explain what is happening? I want a directory listing of my static directory on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files you put in the `/static` folder will be accessible, but flask doesn't do directory listing. So if you put a `script.js` in `/static/js` for instance, you should be able to `GET /static/js/script.js` even though `GET /static` will 404.

Answer (score 1):

You get a 404 because the resource cannot be returned as it is. You get a 200 because the resources does "exist" in the sense that there is a static folder.

Try this out:

http://packages.python.org/Flask-AutoIndex/

You can reveal directory contents and show them in the browser, etc.

Comment: So, originally Flask will not list the files in `static` for me when I `GET` it, right?

Comment: Right you have to enable "directory listing" for any web server, and the Flask-AutoIndex package is the Flask-friendly method in this case.